# Please explain the interaction I observed between a GFCI receptacle and a 3000 volt arc

Tags: high-voltage, arc, gfci

The high voltage leads of a 120 to 3000 volt transformer, current limited to 30 mA, were each wrapped around a small nail. The nails were allowed to rest upon a piece of wood soaked in an electrolyte. The low voltage leads of the same transformer were then connected to one of the building's 120 volt branch circuits and the transformer switched on.

A person then used their hand to grasp the insulation of one of the high voltage leads and lift the nail from the wood, causing an arc to form between the nail and the wood. The nail was lifted until the distance from the nail tip to the wood was such that the arc extinguished.

Immediately after the arc was extinguished, a GFCI receptacle on a **different** circuit than the one powering the transformer tripped. The GFCI receptacle that tripped was certainly on a different circuit, based on careful examination of the exposed NM cable in the building. Moreover, the GFCI receptacle in question is connected in a feed-through configuration, so if the transformer was connected to one of the receptacles on its load side it would have been disabled when the GFCI tripped, but the transformer remained functional after the GFCI tripped.

This was repeated *many* times to confirm that the extinguishing of the electrical arc caused the tripping of the GFCI receptacle.

Strangely enough, when a load (specifically, a group of lamps) was energized through the load terminals of the GFCI receptacle, it ceased to respond to the electrical arc. (A caveat - it may have tripped once in this condition, but this is uncertain. At the very least, this condition greatly attenuates the receptacle's sensitivity.)

Furthermore, connecting the transformer to an extension cord caused the GFCI receptacle to cease responding to the arc, even when the extension cord was supplied from the same receptacle to which the transformer was originally directly connected.

Please explain why the extinguishing arc causes the GFCI receptacle to trip.

Comment: Good question , easy answer for experts or Prof maybe

Comment: There might be some problem in the wiring, or the arc generated electromagnetic interference that caused the GFCI to trip, maybe it already had leakage right below the trip level and any excess interference made it trip. However, for safety reasons, should you really be operating salvaged microwave transformers nearby electrolyte soaked wood anyway, if you are yanking the wires by hand to cause arcs? A lot of people don't understand how dangerous that is, and have no proper safety protocols. The tripping GFCI is the smallest problem if you have an accident.

Comment: Incidentally, it wasn't a salvaged microwave transformer. It is a current-limited neon-sign transformer. I agree that I shouldn't have been so careless, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current in the arc has a negative incremental resistance so the trigger voltage drops low and the arc can be stretched with say > 20 mA but possibly much lower than 3kV. Like SCR's there will be a gap force that when current decreases with length  and rising in ESR in ionized air, the current drops below the extinguish threshold and stops.

When it stops it can be in any phase depending on speed of moving arc.  THe inductance of the loop and short dt that ends the arc both contribute to a much larger voltage but now "maybe" too far away to re-ignite. Oil could detonate, water is safe.

This voltage transient on line voltage and neutral may not be balanced and the differential current is what triggers the GFCI, not actual ground current which is not measured.

However, putting a load on the GFCI damps the spike.

Also adding a more common mode inductance with parasitic mutual capacitance (L/C) i.e. a transmission line or differential choke attenuates the MHz signals in the spike.  The duration of the spike only needs to reach some mA-ms product or A-s to trigger the sensitive spring-loaded relay to latch power off.  Usually rated for < 15mA at line f differential current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdFcHZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir.

But why does putting a load on the GFCI dampen the spike?

And what causes the voltage transient on the line voltage and neutral to be unbalanced?